# Fancybox styling issue with IE8 & IE9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, fancybox, fancybox-2

For some reason, my Fancybox popup does not get any styling in IE8 & IE9 (but in IE7!). It works fine in other browsers.

I have included the `DOCTYPE`, which is a common error.

The [webpage](http://erikshjalpen.se/stodja/gavobutik/) is inherited from an other developer and contains some bad markup. To try the popup, you can click on the title links bellow the products images.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You are using fancyBox [v2.1.4 js](http://erikshjalpen.se/themes/kompago/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js) file with fancyBox [v2.1.5 css](http://erikshjalpen.se/themes/kompago/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css) file. Try matching the correct version of one or another.

Comment: That's true, thanks. Changed it now. The problem is still there however. Do you recognize this?

Comment: according to my IE, you get this js error : `Error : Expected identifier, string or number, Line :50, Char: 88`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Does it say in which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The reason for this was that the `<link>` tag to the .css file was placed outside the `<head>` tag, which IE9 and earlier is especially cranky about.